# automate testing of application executable file (windows based application)

Tags: testing, automation, coded-ui-tests, gui-testing

I have an application executable file (.Exe) which lets user to enter personal information, I want to automate this for testing purpose like I write a script that enter data automatically in those edit box and then hit submit button

I am new to testing, but I have a basic understanding of scripting language like python, ruby, JavaScript, but I don't know how to use them to write scripts for automation testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows-based GUI automation, you can use [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), which is a downloadable, freeware utility.  If you're partial to ruby, check out the [rautomation](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation) gem.

Answer (score 0):

If your application creates native Windows controls, the best choice is [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) package for Python 2.7.